# JavaFX Manipulate Labels from two FXML

Tags: java, javafx, label, clipboard

I have a calculator app, it runs by app.class - main.java using controller.class - controller.java that allows me to manipulate two fxmls - simplecalc.fxml and engineercalc.fxml. Menubar itself coded in app.class.
I managed to use copy button from MenuBar to copy(to Clipboard) data from Label in simplecalc.fxml, but i failed to do so in another fxml - engineercalc. I'm using controllers in app.class to manipulate those labels. How do i copy from two fxmls at the same time?

[Calculator visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojiZO.png)

[Switching between fxmls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INJge.png)

main.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Calcmain extends Application {

    public void start(Stage myStage) throws Exception{
        myStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        BorderPane rootNode = new BorderPane();
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 235, 300);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
        myStage.show();

        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("_File");
        Menu editMenu = new Menu("_Edit");
        Menu viewMenu = new Menu("_View");
        Menu helpMenu = new Menu("_Help");


        fileMenu.setMnemonicParsing(true);
        editMenu.setMnemonicParsing(true);
        viewMenu.setMnemonicParsing(true);
        helpMenu.setMnemonicParsing(true);

        MenuItem openMenu = new MenuItem("Open");
        MenuItem exitMenu = new MenuItem("Exit");
        MenuItem copyMenu = new MenuItem("Copy");
        MenuItem pasteMenu = new MenuItem("Paste");
        MenuItem cutMenu = new MenuItem("Cut");
        MenuItem simpleMenu = new MenuItem("Standard");
        MenuItem engineerMenu = new MenuItem("Engineer");
        MenuItem aboutMenu = new MenuItem("About");

        openMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + O"));
        exitMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + E"));
        copyMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + C"));
        pasteMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + V"));
        cutMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + X"));
        simpleMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + 1"));
        engineerMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + 2"));
        aboutMenu.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(
"shortcut + A"));

        fileMenu.getItems().addAll(openMenu, new SeparatorMenuItem(), exitMenu);
        editMenu.getItems().addAll(copyMenu, pasteMenu, cutMenu);
        viewMenu.getItems().addAll(simpleMenu, new SeparatorMenuItem(), engineerMenu);
        helpMenu.getItems().addAll(aboutMenu);

        exitMenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        simpleMenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                Parent root;
                try {
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Simplecalc.fxml"));
                    rootNode.setCenter(root);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Simplecalc.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController();

        FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Engineercalc.fxml"));
        Controller controller2 = loader2.getController();

        engineerMenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                try {
                    Parent root2 = loader2.load();
                    rootNode.setCenter(root2);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });  
        mb.getMenus().add(fileMenu);
        mb.getMenus().add(editMenu);
        mb.getMenus().add(viewMenu);
        mb.getMenus().add(helpMenu);
        rootNode.setTop(mb);

        rootNode.setCenter(root);

        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard(); 
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    copyMenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {      
                        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                        content.putString(controller.display.getText());
                        clipboard.setContent(content);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });     
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);       
    }
}
```

simplecalc.fxml:

```
<Label fx:id="display" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="175.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
```

engineercalc.fxml:

```
<Label fx:id="display" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="175.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
```

controller.java:

```
@FXML 
Label display;
```

It works only with simplecalc:

```
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString(controller.display.getText());
clipboard.setContent(content);
```

When i try do it with engineercalc:

```
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString(controller2.display.getText());
clipboard.setContent(content);
```

It calls: `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: You need event handlers on your menuItems

Comment: Can you, please, bring a little example in my case?

Comment: Why did you put the clipboad handler in Platform.runLater?

Comment: I found this solution from someone's code, and it worked for me. Without this Platrorm.runLater clipboard was not able to copy label's text

Comment: If it is needed try putting it inside the void handle method around the code inside there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();

copyMenu .setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {            
        final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("get test from textfield and put it here");
        clipboard.setContent(content);

    }
});
```

Comment: By the way, is this method will attach clipboard to label(display)?

Comment: You need to do label.getText() were it says ...Put it here.

Comment: If the last answer was the correct answer for you original question you should have accepted the answer and started a new question.

Comment: In this case, you don't have to accept this answer because the question is different and this answer is not valid for the current question.

Comment: Sorry, i was not familiar with options on this site.
By the way, thank you for your help, your answer gave me a second breath and i was coding all this day, and by now i'm almost finished

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to create a global boolean isStandardShowing. Set is to true is the standard fxml is showing on start up. In Standard event handler set the boolean to true. in the Engineering event handler set the boolean to false. Then use an if statement to pull from the correct display

```
    boolean isStandardShow = true;//This should be global.

    Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard(); 
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                copyMenu.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {      
                    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                    if(isStandardShow)
                    {
                        content.putString(controller.display.getText());
                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        content.putString(OtherContorller.display.getText());
                    }
                    clipboard.setContent(content);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sir, you have done great job to help me. Your guidance helped me to write about 50 percent of my app. I'm very thankful for your help. And for result - all works perfectly, just like i wanted, although code is filled with crutches)

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with the rest of your coding.